# Querying SharePoint list via Graph api errors out with Title not indexed error

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to get SharePoint list item with a filter OData query. It's a `GET` http request with the full URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{GUID-SiteID}/lists/{GUID-ListID}/items?expand=fields&$filter=fields/Title eq 'XXXX'
```

The error from Graph:

[image]

I have already tried the following

1. Added the `Title` column as "indexed":

[image]

2. Tried adding the two headers separately to request

   ```
    "Prefer:allowthrottleablequeries" 
    "Prefer:HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly"
   ```

   but I still get the same error

PS: it was working without adding the headers before. Just adding the column to indexed was enough but not sure what changed and this error is persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, it started working now after 2 days...no idea what fixed it :-(